# Unexpected token: CASE in statement [CASE]

Tags: hsqldb

```
CREATE TEXT TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PPE_COMMON_LOG (LOG_ID int PRIMARY KEY,COMP_NAME varchar(50),LOG_EVENT varchar(50),LOG_LEVEL varchar(30),LOG_MSG varchar(200),LOG_DATETIME datetime,LOG_ERROR_CODE varchar(80) );

Select COUNT(*) as "TCOUNT" From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES Where TABLE_NAME = 'PPE_COMMON_LOG';

CASE TCOUNT WHEN 0 then 
    SET TABLE PPE_COMMON_LOG SOURCE "PPE_COMMON_LOG.csv;ignore_first=true;all_quoted=true";
    SET TABLE PPE_COMMON_LOG SOURCE HEADER "LOG_ID,COMP_NAME,LOG_EVENT,LOG_LEVEL,LOG_MSG,LOG_DATETIME,LOG_ERROR_CODE";
END CASE;
```

It gives "Unexpected token: CASE in statement [CASE]"

Comment: Can anyone please let me know where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The blocks with CASE TCOUNT WHEN 0 is incorrect. You cannot write a CASE statement in SQL to execute other SQL statements.

If you want to execute the SET TABLE statements only in some situations depending on what exists in INFORMATION_SCHEMA, then execute the SELECT in Java and check the return count and execute the other SQL statements depending on the return count.

Comment: thnak you,can you please share me an example regarding it.@fredt

Comment: i am using script runner to run the sql file with database hsqldb so i want all such things to be handle in script rather than using java. Is there anyway to do that

Comment: Try HSQLDB's SqlTool's PL commands. It supports `* IF` conditionals.

Comment: is it possible to write a function within which we can condition and then accordingly execute another sql query

Comment: You cannot run `SET TABLE ...` statements conditionally inside the engine. Use SqlTool.